# Session value in PHP not expiring

Tags: php, session, unset

I have set two session variables set as:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
$_SESSION['last_acted_on'] = time();
```

I am trying to reset the value of the session variable `logged_in` with:

```
<?php

session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['last_acted_on']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_acted_on'] > 120) ){ //2mins
   session_unset('last_acted_on');     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    session_unset('logged_in');
    session_unset();
    unset($_SESSION['last_acted_on']);
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage

    return;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['last_acted_on'] = time();
}


?>
```

But there is no effect and `logged_in` stays as 1. Any advice?

`EDIT`: I have updated my code as:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['last_acted_on']) && (time() - strtotime($_SESSION['last_acted_on']) > 120) ){ //2mins
   unset($_SESSION['last_acted_on']);     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
   unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage

    return;
}

$_SESSION['last_acted_on'] = time();
```

Also, when I refresh the page or navigate back and forth on the page, the session value is unset. Why is it not unset after the time period of 2mins? Please note that the page refresh that is expiring the session variable is calling unsetsession.php file.

Comment: try changing `time() - $_SESSION['last_acted_on']` to `time() - strtotime($_SESSION['last_acted_on'])`

Comment: Why are you updating $_SESSION['last_acted_on'] in your else case  ?

Comment: @Marcus it doesnt make a difference. Still unable to unset the session variable. Please see the `Edit` in the question

Comment: Yes, my bad. I was just assuring that the variable's value was a valid timestamp. There is issue in your session unsetting, as stated by others. I'll update my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is issue with session variable unsetting. If you intend to flush the session itself, you can use `session_destroy()`, which will clear the `$_SESSION` array. Otherwise, you can use the `unset()` function, as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php).

> Note: If $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is
>   used, use unset() to unregister a session variable, i.e. unset
>   ($_SESSION['varname']);.

Or more easily, you can simply set their values to `null` or `0` and you can put a check on their `empty` condition, as below:

```
<?php
session_start();
$session = &$_SESSION;
if( !empty($session['last_acted_on']) && (time() - $session['last_acted_on'] > 120) ){ //2mins
   unset($session['last_acted_on']);     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    unset($session['logged_in']);    
    return;
}
else{
    $session['last_acted_on'] = time();
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['last_acted_on'] = time()` – the value already is an integer timestamp!

Comment: Updated. Please let me know if it's still invalid

Answer (score 0):

Wronng usage of session_unset.

```
void session_unset ( void )
```

What you need is

```
unset($_SESSION['yourvalue'])
```